# Why doesn't ByteArrayOutputStream overrride the write(byte[]) method?

Tags: java, error-handling, language-design

Why doesn't `ByteArrayOutputStream` override the [`OutputStream.write(byte[] b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-byte:A-) method? It only overrides the [`write(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#write-byte:A-int-int-) version taking an offset and length.

Of course, the existing implementation for the `write(byte[] b)` method in `OutputStream` simply delegates to the other method with `offset == 0` and `len == b.length`, so it "works" but not well because now `baos.write(byteArray)` is declared to `throw IOException` *even though it can never throw such an exception*.

For methods that actually take `ByteArrayOutputStream` (or otherwise have an `IOException`-free specialized path, perhaps by casting) this means you are stuck using the long-form `write()`. It's not a fatal flow - but is there any good reason not to have this method overridden? Is there any reason it can't happen in a future JDK (**edit:** yes, there are good reasons, see the comments)?

Comment: Maybe for the same reason `close() throws IOException`.

Comment: It's too late now, since `ByteArrayOutputStream` is not final, and getting rid of the checked exception now could break subclasses that override `write(byte[])` and declare `throws IOException`.

Comment: @MattTimmermans - good point. I guess it would also break (at the source level) anyone who catches IOException specifically around a write call, since you'd get the "nothing in this block can throw that" error.

Comment: If this is a big inconvenience for your code, you could subclass ByteArrayOutputStream yourself, override the `write(byte[])` method, and remove the `throws IOException` declaration. I've only ever passed ByteArrayOutputStreams to other methods that were expecting an `OutputStream` and I think that is the typical usecase.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - yeah, that's one typical use case, but the other big one is just as an expandable byte array for dumping bytes into (like the byte version of `StringBuilder` and much faster and smaller than `ArrayList<Byte>`). In that use, you usually leave it declared as a `BAOS`.